# Force a page refresh using Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, refresh

I have a simple request to refresh a page using a Javascript code below:

```
function tb_closeRefresh() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

This works fine in IE but Firefox just gets the cached version and needs the user to press F5 to get the latest version of the page.

I have added the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

But this does not help.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 11):

you might call the same page but let it look like it is an *other* page by changing the querystring:

```
window.location.href = "index.html" + "?" + Date.parse(new Date());
```

This works for every browser. You could improve it by extracting the current page out of `location.href`.

**Edit:**

If you already have an existing querystring you have to use `&` insead of `?`:

```
window.location.href = "product.aspx?id=prod" + "&" + Date.parse(new Date());
```

Comment: +1, I was just about to post this myself. This is the method I use everytime a page needs to be reloaded through JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just tried this and it did not work. I can only assume that is because I am use URL rewriting to re-write /product_name/ to product.aspx?id=prod. But not sure?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to refresh, you can reset `window.location` to `window.location`.

```
window.location = window.location
```

Assigning `window.location` will perform a redirect, and since `window.location` returns the current location, the statement above will act as a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
function page_reload() 
{ 
   window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php'; 
}
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(0);">Click here to refresh the page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Firefox supports reload, you should use:

```
var myUrl = window.location;
window.location.replace(myUrl)
```

I found that this works in IE, Apple Safari, and Firefox. It does NOT seem to work in Firefox on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

maybe these will work?:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-store">
```

Comment: oh wow... code is deleted in a coding forum?

maybe these will work?:
##<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
##<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-store">

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below for your issue

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh';
```

But you need to using "Pushstate" to update the url, please see this for more details
[window.history.pushState refreshing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307401/window-history-pushstate-refreshing-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

The Docs say to use:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

It should work in all browser including mobile.