# How to remove part of the URL after loading

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

Basically i have a url which gets loaded

```
http://somewebsite.com/Staging/hello/index.php?action=viewByGrid&subdo=show&projectID=-1&stat=1&workStageID=-1
```

After loading. I want the URL to be shown as

```
http://somewebsite.com/Staging/hello/index.php?action=viewByGrid
```

I need to remove the query string, soon after loading in my **document.ready()**

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: change the URL address without redirecting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting)

Comment: see this link my be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307401/window-history-pushstate-refreshing-the-browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `history.replaceState` or `history.pushState`. It's fairly well supported, and does what you want. The former will not insert a new history entry and just modify the current one, while the latter adds a new history entry for the new URL. The first two parameters are not important, the third is what changes the url

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var href = window.location.href,
       newUrl = href.substring(0, href.indexOf('&'))
   window.history.replaceState({}, '', newUrl);
});
```