Using history.pushState() in the following scenario may cause issues after reloading
Steps:

Start a web app from the command line, and of course, the tab page of this web app is the one I wrote.
Use Ctrl+Shift+Delete to clear browser cache.
Using the JS API to launch this web app, additional parameters will be added, such as changing certain parts of the page content.
Using pushState to change history information, for example, pushing a URL like www.aaa.com.
After manipulating the page content, pushState again with the new address, www.bbb.com.
reload
When you reload the page using Ctrl+R or F5, the page content will be www.aaa.com instead of the latest www.bbb.com. Checking the log will reveal that the reload URL is www.bbb.com, but the displayed content is www.aaa.com.

"I'm not sure how to handle this issue. It seems like the browser's steps are correct, but it might also be due to caching."

The browser version is chromium(122.0.6261.117)

I feel like you are simply listing the steps but not trying anything, what JS API are you using? How are you using pushState?...What is your actual issue?

This might be the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424506/8382028
